# Where can I find Ubuntu Minimal 22.04 Docker image?

Tags: docker, ubuntu-minimal

Canonical blog mentions Ubuntu Minimal Docker images: https://canonical.com/blog/minimal-ubuntu-released. When I search Docker Hub for `Ubuntu Minimal` I get `10,000 results for Ubuntu Minimal` where the second one seems to be a normal Ubuntu: https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu. I don't see any `minimal` names or tags. Where is the Ubuntu Minimal Docker image?

Comment: This is the minimum Ubuntu installation:(cloud-images/+oci/ubuntu-base): https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu For example (92 packages Ubuntu 23.04): https://git.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+oci/ubuntu-base/tree/ubuntu-lunar-oci-amd64-root.manifest?h=lunar-23.04  Local analog: debootstrap --variant=minbase

Comment: @JohanPalych Thank you. I've seen it yesterday, but it took a careful reading today to find the single appearance of word *minimal* on this page.

Answer (score 5):

According to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Minimal and accepted answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52063219/minimal-ubuntu-docker-image-is-claimed-to-be-29mb-so-why-does-docker-images-c, there is no publicly available Docker image for Ubuntu Minimal. Additionally, the images Canonical publishes are dated: 16.04 and 18.04.

I ended up using Debian slim: `bookworm-slim` from https://hub.docker.com/_/debian.

---

Minimum Docker image based on `bookworm-slim` is 73.4MB and one based on `ubuntu:22.04` is 77.8MB in size.

Comment: So in other words, the default Ubuntu image is pretty slim to begin with ..

Comment: @ArturMeinild Unless you care about 4.4MB you can save by using Debian...

Comment: If you want to go minimal, use Alpine as base image. But I doubt 20-25 MB make much difference for anyone these days.

Comment: Alpine might give you more headache than free megabytes: https://dev.to/asyazwan/moving-away-from-alpine-30n4